# What will the major/minor differences be between ruby 1.9.2 and ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2

I've been told that ruby 1.9.2 is ruby 2.0 but ruby 1.9.3 is slated to be released in the near future and it will contain some performance enhancements.

So what are they planning for 2.0? Will it be much different than ruby 1.9.x?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Two features that are already implemented in YARV, and which will most likely end up in Ruby 2.0, are traits (`mix`) and `Module#prepend`.

The `mix` method, unlike the current `include` method, takes a *list* of modules, and mixes all of them in at the same time, making sure that they have no conflicting methods. It also gives you a way to easily resolve conflicts, if e.g. two modules you want to mix in define the same method. So, basically, while the `include` method allows you to treat a module as a mixin, the `mix` method allows you to treat a module as a trait.

`Module#prepend` mixes a module into a class or module, again just like `include` does, but instead of inserting it into the inheritance chain just *above* the class, it inserts is just *below* the class. This means that methods in the module can override methods in the class, and they can delegate to the overriden methods with `super`, both of which is not possible when using `include`. This basically makes `alias_method_chain` obsolete.

One feature that has been discussed for a couple of months (or 10 years, depending on how you count), are Refinements. There has been discussion for over 10 years now to add a way to do scoped, safe monkey patching in Ruby. I.e. a way where I can monkey patch a core class, but only my code sees that monkey patch, other code doesn't. For many years, the frontrunner for that kind of safe monkey patching were Selector Namespaces, however more recently, Classboxes have been getting a lot of attention, and even more recently, a prototype implementation and specification of Refinements, a variant of Classboxes, was put forward.

Generally speaking, the big theme of Ruby 2.0 is scalability: scaling *up* to bigger teams, bigger codebases, bigger problem sizes, bigger machines, more cores. But also scaling *down* to smaller machines like embedded devices.

The three features I mentioned above are for scaling to bigger teams and bigger codebases. Some proposed features for scaling to bigger problem sizes and more cores are parallel collections and parallel implementations of `Enumerable` methods such as `map`, as well as better concurrency abstractions such as futures, promises, agents, actors, channels, join patterns or something like that.